# combine 2 varchar column's data and convert to datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have 2 columns in a table of varchar datatype.

date and type are the column names in table.

the data present in the table looks like this

```
date        time
20090610    132713
20090610    132734
```

i need ms sql server query to concatenate these 2 columns data and display as datetime format.

Note : 
1. the datatype of those 2 columns cannot be changed now.
2. i tried

```
select convert(datetime,date + time)
```

it says "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

Suggest the possible solution.

Comment: your format is wrong, i suggest google, 'convert string to datetime' and check there for string format. if you look at what you wrote, you are trying convert(datetime, '20090610132713'), and that (in short) suck balls

Comment: Is there a way some how solve this now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will return a datetime. The bottom line is to be replaced by your table

```
select convert(datetime,date,112)+
coalesce(stuff(stuff(rtrim(time), 5,0,':'), 3,0,':'), '') newdate
from 
(VALUES ('20090610','132713'),('20090610', '132734'),('20090610', '      ')) yourtable(date,time)
```

Result:

```
newdate
2009-06-10 13:27:13.000
2009-06-10 13:27:34.000
2009-06-10 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: @whytheq stuff is really underestimated. very often people uses valuable cpu to canculate the length of a varchar before removing the first character. Example: 'substring(vchar, 2, len(vchar) - 1)' Can be written 'stuff(vchar, 1,1, '')'

Comment: tho, it is powerfull function in sql server, it there are limitation that can be avoided with the other functions

Comment: @t-clausen.dk i altered the query of yours like this select convert(datetime,date,112)+stuff(stuff(time, 5,0,':'), 3,0,':') newdate
from 
mytablename. It is showing the values correctly but it is not handling null values present in time column.

Comment: @t-clausen.dk in one of the rows , time column's data was empty. it throwed the exception The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Comment: @t-clausen.dk oops sorry ! there was not null value, but there was '     ' in time'es column. i.e in between single quotes there were 6 empty spaces

Comment: what do you want returned when time equals 6 blanks ?

Comment: @t-clausen.dk hmmm, time part replaced by zeros is fine

Answer (score 0):

You can get it using

```
SELECT 
convert(varchar, convert(datetime, date), 111)
+ ' ' + substring(time, 1, 2)
+ ':' + substring(time, 3, 2)
+ ':' + substring(time, 5, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #Table 
(
[date] VARCHAR(100),
[time] VARCHAR(100)
)
INSERT INTO #Table VALUES
('20090610','132713'),
('20090610','132734')   

;WITH Bits_CTE
    AS
    (
    SELECT 
        [Date],
        [Time],
        [hrs] = CONVERT(INT,SUBSTRING([Time], 1, 2)),
        [mns] = CONVERT(INT,SUBSTRING([Time], 3, 2)),
        [secs] = CONVERT(INT,SUBSTRING([Time], 5, 2))
    FROM #Table
    )
SELECT 
    [Date],
    [Time],
    DATEADD(HOUR,[hrs],
    DATEADD(MINUTE,[mns],
    DATEADD(SECOND,[secs],[Date]))) 
FROM Bits_CTE
```

Comment: This seems alot of work comparing with the solution i provided

Comment: @t-clausen.dk agreed - but mine looks pretty and is a valid alternative

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DateTimeAdd] 
( 
      @datepart         date, 
      @timepart         time 
) 
RETURNS datetime2 
AS 
BEGIN 
      RETURN DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @datepart), CAST(@timepart AS datetime2)); 
END
```

Sorry - Missed the bit in your question about storing the date and time as varchars.  You would therefore still need to convert these data itemsbefore using this function.

Comment: if the fields were date and time, all you had to do was datepart + timepart. However they are of the type varchar, so your function will not work